# Return vector from pthread function?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

having some trouble finding out the syntax around returning a vector from a pthread function. Here's currently what I have:

```
typedef struct vectorData {
    vector v1;
    vector v2;
} vectorData;

void *vectorAddThread(void *arg) {
    vectorData *data = (vectorData *)arg;
    vector v1 = data->v1;
    vector v2 = data->v2;
    vector result = {v1->x + v2->x, v1->y + v2->y, v1->z + v2->z};
    return (void*) result;
}
```

I'm getting errors on the last two lines about the return result, and the the adding part. Thanks

Comment: What is the type of 'vector'?   If it's a struct, then 'return (void*) result;' will pretty clearly not work.  maybe 'return (void*) &result;' would compile, but signaling such a pointer from a thread is bad. malloc a *vector,, load it and return that.

Comment: Returning `result` doesn't work because it's on the stack and it's _not_ a pointer/address (you'd need `&result`), so when the function terminates, the pointer that the main thread gets back [via `pthread_join`] is no longer valid. Consider either returning the value in the _original_ vector via: `*data = vector` OR use `malloc`: `vector *result = malloc(sizeof(vector)); result->x = v1->x + v2->x; result->y = v1->y + v2->y; result->z = v1->z + v2->z; return result;`

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a `struct` to a `void *` pointer. You need dynamically allocate a `vector` in your case with `malloc`, and return the pointer.

```
vector *result = malloc(sizeof(vector));
result->x = ?;
result->y = ?;
result->z = ?;
return (void *)result;
```

Now that would solve the issue of returning a `struct` from a function that returns `void *`. But if you're using pthreads you shouldn't be returning objects from them, you need to pass the `vector` to it as user data in `arg`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easiest:

```
typedef struct vectorData {
    vector v1;
    vector v2;
    vector result;
} vectorData;
```

Saves messing about with dubious thread-stack vars, mallocs etc. and ties the result output directly to the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The thread start function in pthread library returns a pointer to void.  Can return any pointer type by type-casting it to (void *). The return value can be accessed by pthread_join(3).

However, a vector needs the type of element information also. Not sure if type-casting it to (void *) and accessing it again will work fine. Using it as an element of structure seems better.

In the following example, I am returning a pointer to structure from the thread start function. The structure contains a vector and two character arrays. You can change it according to your requirement. I am using two pointers to show that data is copied on the variable used for pthread_join(3).

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <vector>

    void *functionPthread(void *);

    struct retStruct
    {
            std::vector<int> vecNumber;
            char name[20];
            char city[20];
    };

    struct retStruct *r2;
    struct retStruct *r1;

    int main()
    {
            int rc, i;
            pthread_t th;

            r2 = (retStruct*) malloc(sizeof(retStruct));
            memset(r2, '\0', sizeof(r2));

            if(rc = pthread_create(&th, NULL, &functionPthread, NULL))
            {
                    printf("Thread creation failed, return code %d, errno %d", rc,                 errno);
            }

            pthread_join(th, (void**)&r2);

            for(i = 0; i < r2->vecNumber.size(); i++)
                    printf("Vectore element at index %d = %d\n", i, r2->vecNumber.at(i));

            printf("Name: %s, City: %s, Vector Number: %d\n", r2->name, r2->city, r2->vecNumber.front());
            free(r1);
            free(r2);
            return 0;
    }

    void *functionPthread(void *)
    {
            r1 = (retStruct*) malloc(sizeof(retStruct));
            memset(r1, '\0', sizeof(r1));
            strcpy(r1->name, "xxxx");
            strcpy(r1->city, "yyyy");
            r1->vecNumber.push_back(11);
            r1->vecNumber.push_back(12);
            return r1;
    }
```